# Embedded, linq-enabled database for small-scale c# applications

Tags: c#, database, linq

I'm looking for a database system for a C# project which fulfills the following criteria:

- Embeddable, i.e. does not need an extra server. Should also be usable without the user having to install some sort of local server, mostly because the users do not have admin permissions on the PC and thus can't install anything.
- Should be possible to query it using C# / LINQ
- It needs to be able to save its files on a network drive!! This is because on our office PCs, all local drives are unaccessible for regular users and all the other drives are network drives. Unfortunately, this basically kills Microsoft SQL Server Compact and SQL Server Express since neither of them allows their files to be saved on network drives (very smart, Microsoft :( )

I'm currently exploring SQLite / NHibernate to Linq, but that's quite a lot of heavy stuff to integrate for a small application. I was hoping there might be something that natively supports my requirements (sql server compact would've been perfect if it wasn't for the network drive restriction).

So if any of you have an idea which system I could use, I'd be glad to hear some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Even user's temp folders are disabled to write to?! O_o

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question seems to be :
SQLite - small, embeddable, db fits in a single file.

You can connect to SQLite using an SQLite .Net provider.
You can query SQLite using LINQ after you use an ORM (like Entity Framework, or NHibernate or Lightspeed).

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I'll use SQLite and NHibernate then if there's no simple solution available. I've done a couple of tests now and it seems to work just fine, although I suppose it's a bit of overkill for an Excel-addin heh.. :)

Comment: @Bogey The SQLite .NET component is about 1MB, NHibernate is 2-3 IIRC -- if size is important. Something like SubSonic is like LINQ2SQL (and "sqlmetal") in that it uses templates to generate the code first.